# Convert varchar date with text to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, casting

I have a varchar(255) column in my SQL database containing timestamps. I need to convert this to a datetime format. However I am not sure which cast/convert is appropriate.

Format looks like:

```
DDD, DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

Data examples:

```
Tue, 9 Sep 2014 07:24:25 +0000
Mon, 30 Jun 2014 20:18:19 -0530
```

The timezone indicators after the second(SS) digits can be ignored.

Desired result: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: And this is why you dont store dates in varchar columns

Comment: As Jamiec mentioned, you should store dates as dates in database. Formatting and display is work of application. There are plenty of options on UI side to perform date formatting in almost any platform.

Comment: I agree, but I don't have ownership over the DB :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your format ALWAYS look like that your can use the following

```
Select convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateColumn, CharIndex(',', DateColumn) + 1, LEN(DateColumn) - (CharIndex(',', DateColumn) + 1 + CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(DateColumn)) - 4))))
```

Here is my example:

```
Declare @val varchar(40) = 'Tue, 9 Sep 2014 07:24:25 +0000'
Declare @val1 varchar(40) = 'Mon, 30 Jun 2014 20:18:19 -0530 (PST)'

Select convert(datetime, substring(@val, CharIndex(',', @val) + 1, Len(@val) - (CharIndex(',', @val) + 1 + CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@Val)) - 4))) 
Select convert(datetime, substring(@val1, CharIndex(',', @val1) + 1, Len(@val1) - (CharIndex(',', @val) + 1 + CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@Val1)) - 4)))
```

Comment: I like this method, but apparently I was not thoroughly enough with the samples. 'Sun, 14 Dec 2014 08:38:25 -0800 (PST)' This one can also appear..

Comment: I've changed it. Not fixed anymore

Comment: Actually it could be simplified a bit. But your help lead my to the solution: convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(date,6,20)) Thx!

Comment: You can but then you have to trim it, because the day does not always have a prefix 0

Answer (score 0):

Extract the different parts using substring, take one extra character because of one or two digit days.
E.g. year part: `trim(substring(col from 12 for 5))`

Do similar for the rest of the items.
Month needs extra work to get month number from month name

```
case trim(substring(col from 8 for 4))
  when 'Jan' then '01'
  when 'Feb' then '02'
  ...
  when 'Dec' then '12'
end
```

Concat your different parts, don't forget separating dashes etc.